# Should I write condition/domain or not?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Should I write condition for this

${x\over y}(1-{x\over (x+y)})+({x\over y})^{-1} (1-{y\over x+y})$

Condition would be $x+y≠0 ; x≠-y ; y≠0$ if I'm right.
I'm not sure about $x≠0$ though.

My question is should I write condition in the first place because the sum of all this is equal to 1.

Comment: $x \neq 0$ because $\left({x \over y}\right)^{-1}$ right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The domain of the function $t\mapsto t^{-1}$ is $\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}$, so yes, you really should include it.

Comment: Yes but my question is should I write condition in the first place because the sum of all this is equal of 1.

Comment: It's equal to the constant function $1$ *on its domain*. As always, one evaluates the domain of validity of a calculation before doing it, not after.